# How to assert with PHPUnit a route outputs a CSV

Tags: csv, phpunit

I'm brand new to testing and already I've hit a test I don't know how to write.  I have a route in my application that all it does is generate a CSV file from some online data.  I need to test to see if that CSV file is created.  How do I do that.  Here is my route:

`...generate data...`

```
$strContent = "'Title', 'MediaId', 'Original File Name'". "'\n";
foreach ($objData->media_list as $objMedia) {
    $strContent .= "'" . $objMedia->title . "', '" . $objMedia->media_id . "', '" . $objMedia->original_filename . "'\n";
}

    /**
     * Comment this line out to output file
     */
    // exit;

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Limelight.csv');

    echo $strContent;
    exit;
```

And here is my test:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->call('GET', '/limelight');
    $this->assertFileExists('Limelight.csv');
}
```

The test fails, but I'm not even sure it's the right test.  The file is not saved to the filesystem.  It is output directly to the browser.  How do I test for that in PHPUnit?

Comment: By the way, I'm using Laravel, so if that has any appropriate methods, that could be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something more simple like:

```
public function testCsv(){
    $response = $this->call('GET', $urlToControllerThatGeneratesCsvDownload);
    $this->assertTrue(strpos($response->content(), 'csv') !== false);
}
```

And in Controller the csv was created like this:

```
return \Excel::create('XXXXX', function($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) {
        .....
    });
})->download('csv');
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

How about grabbing the file with file_get_contents() and dumping it to a variable, which you can then test for size, content, etc.:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$this->assertTrue(strlen($data) > $someThreshold);
$this->assertTrue(preg_match('/someString/', $data));
$this->assertEquals($knownHash, md5($data));
```

Or if you want to be really thorough, you can scan each line to make sure it's a valid CSV and contains what you expect:

```
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
while (true) {
    $line = fgetcsv($fp);
    if (feof($fp)) {
        break;
    }
    $this->assertTrue(is_array($line));
    $this->assertTrue(count($line) === $expectedNumberOfItems);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: The problem is is that the file is not saved to the filesystem.  It is output directly to the browser.

Comment: Right, note the use of $url -- the remote address for the file. I.e., it doesn't need to be saved locally in order to test it, you can pull it directly into PHP.

Comment: Er wait, what does call() do? Does it actually hit a server? Or is it a mock?

Comment: call() calls a URL.  It's not a mock.

Comment: Right ok, so then you can use file_get_contents() on that URL to store the contents of the file it serves in a PHP variable.

Comment: OK, but how do I check that it's a CSV?

Comment: Do you mean, how do you check that the contents of the file contain comma-separated strings? Or, how do you check that the file would end up with a name that ends with CSV?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things to `unit test` in your code:

1. that the CSV is (correctly) generated
2. that the script actually sends the CSV

For #1 the problem is that `$strContent` is a local variable and is not publicly exposed. One way to validate it is to extract the CSV generation code into another method, and unit test that method.

For #2 again you need some helper method/class that you use it as a `bridge` between your code and the native PHP code. For example:

```
class MyHttpResponse {
    public function header($header, $replace=false, $httpCode=200) {
        header($location, $replace, $httpCode);
    }

    public function sendBody($body) {
        echo $body;
    }
}
```

and have your original code call methods from there instead of the PHP native ones. You can then use `mocks` or `fakes` in order to assert that the proper `headers` and `body` were sent. Asserting on the `body` of the response also covers the tests from #1, so you can skip those if you do the proper asserts on `body`.

One thing you'll want to keep in mind when writing code that you plan to unit test it, is that you should delegate as much as possible work to other methods/classes. This is not just for the benefit on `unit testing`, it will also bring you to [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In terms of SRP, your `index` method it a little bit overwhelmed, and should not be responsible for generating a string from an array of data, that should be the role of a data processor class/method.